# Determining what elements have changes within them once an action occurs on a page?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to reverse-engineer a certain functionality on a website, and I'm trying to track the events that occur (added classes or changed attributes) when a certain button is pressed. I can't find anything in the code that is relevant, so is there a way to see this in-browser, possibly via Chrome Dev Tools?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what kind of change you want to act upon, you can set an automatic breakpoint for either DOM modifications or event listeners. As covered [on the developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints#dom):

> To set a DOM change breakpoint:
>
> - Click the **Elements** tab in the devtools.
> - Go the element that you want to set the breakpoint on.
> - Right-click the element.
> - Hover over **Break on** then select **Subtree modifications**, **Attribute modifications**, or **Node removal**.

[image: Sample image]

The article also covers all the other possible automatic breakpoint setting possibilities, so be sure to check the rest of it out as well.